# Second loop on Wordpress page not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Disclaimer: I am trying to help someone with adding another section to their Wordpress site. I did not write most of this code.

I am using a different custom post type for each WP_Query loop. Both loops work fine on their own, but when I try to run them on the same page, the second one doesn't show any posts.

Things I have tried:

- wp_reset_query();
- wp_reset_postdata();
- changing the names of $query and $args so each is unique
- moving the reset function to inside if() (but still outside the while loop)

I have looked at every post I can find on the subject and tried all the suggestions, but nothing is working. Surely I am missing something.. Maybe another set of eyes can help me find the problem. I have posted the relevant code below.

```
/* ---- First Loop ---- */
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'casestudies',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
                        
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
            $query->the_post();

            /* ---- Do Stuff ---- */

        endwhile;               
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>

/* ---- Second Loop ---- */
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'whitepages',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
                        
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
            $query->the_post();

            /* ---- Do Stuff ---- */    
                                
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

### Edit:

I found the solution with help from the accepted answer. I posted what I did to fix everything in another answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just tried this code in my local environment, with the only change being the `post_type` values in you `$args` arrays, it seems to be working fine.

What I would recommend doing, as it is as follows:

1. Double checking the value for `post_type` matches the post type's slug. This could just be a case of misspelling, and it's something that tripped me up more times than I'd like to admit over the years.
   You can find this by going to `functions.php` and looking for `register_post_type` function calls.
2. Checking whether there are in fact published posts under that post type. Again, this is something I've been caught out by a few times too.

Additionally, you might want to think about perhaps neatening up the code a little, just to prevent potentially missing something and also to make it more manageable in the future.
Looping over an available post types array where you then construct a `WP_Query` for each of the available post types is my preference of going about a task like what you described, it looks like this:

```
<?php
    $post_types       = array( 'yourposttype', 'yourotherposttype' );
    $common_arguments = array(
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
?>

<?php foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ): ?>
    <?php
        $post_type_argument = array( 'post_type' => $post_type );
        $arguments          = array_merge( $common_arguments, $post_type_argument );
        $query              = new WP_Query( $arguments );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php // Example output ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This way if you ever need to show another post type, you can add it to the `$post_types` array without having to duplicate blocks of code.

And finally, you were correct when you used `wp_reset_postdata()`, it's the recommended function to run after looping over a custom `WP_Query`, `wp_reset_query()` is a little superfluous in this case.
[You can read this answer by Stephen Harris for a bit more depth.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144344)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Each of these loops are located in separate sections of the page with other sections between them. Each uses a carousel container to show cards for posts that match the custom post type. Would something like what you posted work for that? Seems like I need to do it separately, but I could be wrong.

The post_type names are correct, and there are posts for each (each loop works just fine when it is the first loop on the page), but it still is not working for me.

Comment: I see. So since the loops are separated by HTML markup, it's probably best to stick to the code in your question, though I'd recommend cutting down on the duplication of common arguments anyways. As for what the problem might be, the only thing I can think of is that there is some PHP in between the two loops that is not allowing the second loop to run. Have a look for any other unrelated loops that perhaps don't have `wp_reset_postdata()` after the actual loop. Do also have a look at the link in my answer as missing `wp_reset_postdata` aren't the only things that can break a template.

Comment: Well I figured out what was wrong--it was the javascript function associated with the carousel id. It was being re-used for both carousels and that's why it wasn't showing up. I posted what I did in a new answer. I'm still going to upvote your answer, because you helped me with the WP_Query stuff. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! It was not, in fact, the WP_Query() loops causing the issue, but the carousels holding the posts being displayed. Each loop places custom posts into a carousel, and I was re-using the same id for each of the carousels on the page. This did not play nice with the JavaScript.

To correct this, I made a copy of the JavaScript function in the main js file, but changed the #original-name to #other-name. I also changed carousel id to other-name.

Everything now works as intended. Thank you @tomekpryjma for helping me confirm that my loops looked good so that I could stop fixating on that being the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` after while loop solved the problem.